# Razor components - cascading parameter values

Tags: c#, razor, components, blazor

How do you pass a reference to the parent RenderingFragment to the child component/content when creating a razor component in c# (NOT using .razor) ComponentBase overloading the protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder) seems not to work as expected.

Comment: Can you provide a code context ? What did you try so far ?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same question when i wanted to cascade a component to its child components. Solved it as shown below:

```
builder.OpenComponent<CascadingValue<TValue>>(0);
builder.AddAttribute(1, "Value", this);
builder.AddAttribute(2, "ChildContent", (RenderFragment)((builder2) => {
            builder2.AddContent(3, ChildContent);
        }));
builder.CloseComponent();
```

Good luck!